# flip cascade of html

Tags: html, cascade

Noobie question but interesting one aswell.

Is there anyway to reverse the flow of HTML documents so that things automatically hang to the bottom right and go up from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
<HTML dir="RTL">
```

To make things attach to the right.

For top to bottom you'd have to do that yourself, or in a script.

Just for fun I'll see if I can write something using jQuery. I'll post it here.

Try this:

```
function rev(el) {
  $('>*', el).each(function () {
    rev(this);
    $(this).prependTo(el);
  })
}

rev($('body'));
```

That was kinda fun :)

Do this as well, for more fun:

```
$('body *')
 .contents()
 .each(function() {
   if(this.nodeType == 3) { 
     this.textContent = this.textContent.
      replace(/a/g, 'ɐ').
      replace(/b/g, 'q').
      replace(/c/g, 'ɔ').
      replace(/d/g, 'p').
      replace(/e/g, 'ǝ').
      replace(/f/g, 'ɟ').
      replace(/g/g, 'ƃ').
      replace(/h/g, 'ɥ').
      replace(/i/g, 'ı').
      replace(/j/g, 'ɾ').
      replace(/k/g, 'ʞ').
      replace(/l/g, 'ʃ').
      replace(/m/g, 'ɯ').
      replace(/n/g, 'u').
      replace(/o/g, 'o').
      replace(/p/g, 'd').
      replace(/q/g, 'b').
      replace(/r/g, 'ɹ').
      replace(/s/g, 's').
      replace(/t/g, 'ʇ').
      replace(/u/g, 'n').
      replace(/v/g, 'ʌ').
      replace(/w/g, 'ʍ').
      replace(/x/g, 'x').
      replace(/y/g, 'ʎ').
      replace(/z/g, 'z').
      replace(/A/g, '∀').
      replace(/B/g, '').
      replace(/C/g, 'Ↄ').
      replace(/D/g, '◖').
      replace(/E/g, 'Ǝ').
      replace(/F/g, 'Ⅎ').
      replace(/G/g, '⅁').
      replace(/H/g, 'H').
      replace(/I/g, 'I').
      replace(/J/g, 'ſ').
      replace(/K/g, '⋊').
      replace(/L/g, '⅂').
      replace(/M/g, 'W').
      replace(/N/g, 'ᴎ').
      replace(/O/g, 'O').
      replace(/P/g, 'Ԁ').
      replace(/Q/g, 'Ό').
      replace(/R/g, 'ᴚ').
      replace(/S/g, 'S').
      replace(/T/g, '⊥').
      replace(/U/g, '∩').
      replace(/V/g, 'ᴧ').
      replace(/W/g, 'M').
      replace(/X/g, 'X').
      replace(/Y/g, '⅄').
      replace(/Z/g, 'Z').
      replace(/!/g, '¡').
      replace(/"/g, '„').
      replace(/&/g, '⅋').
      replace(/'/g, ',').
      replace(/,/g, '\'').
      replace(/\(/g, ')').
      replace(/\)/g, '(').
      replace(/\./g, '˙').
      replace(/1/g, 'Ɩ').
      replace(/2/g, 'ᄅ').
      replace(/3/g, 'Ɛ').
      replace(/4/g, 'ᔭ').
      replace(/5/g, 'ϛ').
      replace(/6/g, '9').
      replace(/7/g, 'Ɫ').
      replace(/8/g, '8').
      replace(/9/g, '6').
      replace(/0/g, '0').
      replace(/;/g, '؛').
      replace(/</g, '>').
      replace(/>/g, '<').
      replace(/{/g, '}').
      replace(/}/g, '{')
   }
 });
```

Comment: That is hilarious.  If you throw in a `$("html").attr("dir", "RTL");` to the end, it does it all at once!  Makes for a fun bookmarklet.

Answer (score -1):

Oh, that's rather easy if you are using a laptop or a tablet.  If you have a desktop, however, it can be harder to get the display to stay upright.  Sometimes duct tape and some creative woodwork can help.

If your monitor is attached, however, then no.  HTML always renders from the top down.